# FormGroup.valuesChanges, with custom input, returns previous value

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uv49pb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

When using a formGroup with a custom input, the valueChanges observable is firing with the old value each time the user types. That is only happening with the `updateOn: blur` option.

The expected result would be to have the current value.

So I have a an AbstractControlValueAccessor helper:

```
export class AbstractInput implements ControlValueAccessor {
    @Input() value: any = '';
    public disabled: boolean;
    protected onTouchedFn = (any?: any) => { };
    protected onChangeFn = (any?: any) => { };

    constructor() {}

    // Called when patchValue or setValue is called on the form control
    // Allows Angular to update the model
    writeValue(value: any): void {
        this.value = value;
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.onChangeFn = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.onTouchedFn = fn;
    }

    setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        this.disabled = isDisabled;
    }

}
```

I have my custom input

```
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-input',
  template: `
        {{ value | json }}
    <input 
    #inp
    inputApp
    type="text"
    [value]="value"
    (input)="onChange(inp.value)"/>
  `,
  providers: [ 
    makeAccessorProvider(CustomInputComponent)
  ]
})
export class CustomInputComponent extends AbstractInput  {

  onChange(value: string) {
        this.onTouchedFn();
        this.writeValue(value);
        this.onChangeFn(value);
    }

    onTouched() {
        this.onTouchedFn();
    }
}
```

and I have a component that use the custom input and checks when the value of the formGroup changes.
However the value in the console is always the previous value.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`
    <form [formGroup]="group">
      <custom-input formControlName="name"></custom-input>
    </form>`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  group: FormGroup;
  value: any;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.group = this.fb.group({
      name: ['initial value']
    }, { updateOn: 'blur' });
    this.group.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      console.log(this.group.value);
      this.value = this.group.value;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First : you have to add (blur) event in your custom control to call the `onTouchedFn` method when the emlement lost focus.

Second : you have to change the order of calling the events in the onChange method so you have to call `this.onChangeFn(value);`before `this.onTouchedFn();`

Or

Separate the `this.onTouchedFn()` to be called in the custom input blur event and just keep `onChangeFn(value)` inside `onChange` method

what happen in your code is you are calling onTouchedFn method so you want to notify the form control that your input element is fired the blur event (but you didn't pass the final value) so `this.group.valueChanges.subscribe` will not fire after this you call onChangeFn with the value which is going to be cached for the next blur event , then you type again a new value , calling onTouchedFn so at this point `this.group.valueChanges.subscribe` will fire with the last passed data which is the previous value

```
  onChange(value: string) {
            this.writeValue(value);
            this.onChangeFn(value);
            this.onTouchedFn();
}
```

Comment: The first point is wrong though but the second point is right

Comment: it's wrong because I don't want to notify on blur, it depends on the updateOn, and the updateOn isn't always blur. But I'll accept if you modify

Comment: you can make both , (input) and (blur) , I'll modify it :)

Comment: actually you should move onTouchedFn out of onChange because (input) event fires every time you change the value and you don't want to notify blur event on each keypress